# How can I restore files of old HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, restore

I have an old HDD which I've not used in the last 5 years (Seagate Barracuda 2TB). As far as I remember, this disk was the main one for PC, so I'd bet Windows is installed. In order to restore old files, I decided to buy a HDD to USB adapter (TooQ TQE-3527B), because if I connect the HDD to the motherboard, the bios isn't even recognizing it. When I plug in the adapter and connect it to the PC, windows makes a sound like when a USB is connected, but then says it cannot be recognized.
Is there any way to recover the data? I guess that if windows was installed in it, it is normal that it cannot be used like a USB device, but I find no other way if the motherboard isn't even recognizing it.

Comment: Do you need the files?  Not run for 5 years likely means a trip to a local recovery agency.

Comment: Data inside this drive is not essential, as I've not needed it in the past 5 years. Anyway, I'm courious about ways of recovering it without the need to go to a specialist, as I would bet the hard drive was not damaged, just unused.

Comment: If unused for 5 years the drive may be stuck. This happens.

Comment: If this is the case, there is no other way of solving it than putting it in specialist hands? Moreover, I remember trying to restore the data long time ago, and having the same problem of bios not recognizing it. Could it be a corrupted partition or something similar?

Comment: It could be corrupted data, but long period unused also suggests the drive motor. I would get an estimate from a local recovery agency to see.

Comment: Okey! I'll probably go to get a quote. Lastly, is there anyway to restore the HDD? So I can at least use it despite losing the data

Comment: I wouldn't trust it any more. It's failed once, throw it away.

Comment: If you assume it's dead, but want to experiment, try putting it in a freezer... though many say it's of no help, it did get one HDD I had to read old data. https://www.gillware.com/hard-drive-data-recovery/hard-drive-freezer-data-recovery-myth/ .Also, an HDD has some *powerful* rare-earth magnets worth saving.